# Authorization failed while attempting to communicate with CD Discovery Service on Publish

Tags: web8, publishing

A client's onsite SDL Web 8 instance threw an error when publishing the `Publish Settings` to Staging and Live:

`Authorization failed while attempting to communicate with CD Discovery Service 'http://client-site:8082/discovery.svc'. Please make sure the proper credentials have been configured in the Topology Manager for the CD Environment.`

The error seems to only occur for the `Publish Settings` page as we were able to successfully publish other pages to Staging/Live.

Based on the error, we checked that credentials used to define the CD Environment via Topology Manager is correct by successfully retrieving a token from the Token service.

Next, we successfully ran the `Publish Settings` page and component template through Template Builder. There were no custom TBBs used in either template.

Then we investigated the logs for the Discovery and Deployer Service and found no errors. Our team and the client have not updated credentials on the Staging/Live environment.

**Resolution:** We ended up restarting the Publisher which resolved the issue but we're curious as to what could have caused the error to occur in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the publishing queue is showing that the publishing is failing in the transporting phase. In a load balanced environment, it is important to make sure that all your publishers can connect to the discovery services using the Security that is configured  at cd_transport. I can see it happen under the following scenarios.

- One of your publishers is or was unable to connect to the
  discovery services
- The timeout settings in the cd_transport will
  have to be adjusted (you will see a different error though)
- Your publisher or transporter was not being restarted after securing the connection to the discovery service or changes made to the transport
- Make sure that the publisher and the transporter services are properly
  configured across a load balanced environment across different zones
  (if applicable)

Can you also update your question with the logs from your transporter?

Hope it helps!